# Keras ImageDataGenerator setting mean and std

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a pretrained keras model and I want to use it on new dataset. I have weights, mean and std file from the pretrained model and I want to use flow_from_directory from Image Data Generator to load the new dataset. The problem is how can I set the mean and std file for normalization explicitly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is writing your own method to process the samples generated by `flow_from_directory`. It could be something like:

```
def custom_normilze_generator(directory, mean):
    for img in flow_from_directory(directory):
        yield (img - mean)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can just use the 'featurewise_center' and 'featurewise_std_normalization' of ImageDataGenerator to handle that. Reference: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class

Say, the mean [R, G, B] value of your pre-trained dataset is [123.68, 116.779, 103.939], and the std is 64.0. You can then use the example code below: (using Keras 2 with TF backend, image_data_format='channels_last')

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,
                                   featurewise_std_normalization=True)
datagen.mean = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939], dtype=np.float32).reshape((1,1,3)) # ordering: [R, G, B]
datagen.std = 64.
batches = datagen.flow_from_directory(DATASET_PATH + '/train',
                                      target_size=(224,224),
                                      color_mode='rgb',
                                      class_mode='categorical',
                                      shuffle=True,
                                      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: Isn't datagen.std also a list of 3 elements for RGB channels

Comment: I think this answer is obsolete, since the Image data preprocessing API has changed in recent versions of Keras.  But if you really care about how the old API works, the relevant source code could be found here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.1.6/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L803-L805.

Comment: Following up on the previous comment, datagen.std could be either 3 elements or only 1 element.  (`x /= (self.std + K.epsilon())`)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom functor to calculate, store and retrieve the statistics:

```py
class Normaliser():
    def __init__(self, mean=None, std=None):
        self.mean = mean
        self.std = std

    def __call__(self, img):
        if self.mean is not None:
            img = self.center(img)
        if self.std is not None:
            img = self.scale(img)
        return img

    def center(self, img):
        return img - self.mean

    def scale(self, img):
        return img / self.std

    def normalise(self, img):
        return (img - self.mean) / self.std

    def set_mean(self, filepaths, input_size):
        print("Calculating mean with shape: ", input_size)
        self.mean = # calculate the mean
        print("Mean is:", self.mean)
        return True

    def set_std(self, filepaths):
        self.std = # calculate the std
        return False
```

To use it, given an input size of `input_size`, pass an instance of the Normaliser to the `ImageDataGenerator`.

```py
normaliser = Normaliser()
img_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=normaliser)
```

Get the filepaths using of the keras preprocessing utilities. I used `flow_from_directory`

```py
iterator = img_gen.flow_from_directory(directory, input_size=input_size)
```

Then setting the mean of the `normaliser` with

```py
normaliser.set_mean(iterator.filepaths, input_size)
```

You can then save your statistics the way you want.
In the prediction phase, you recreate the `Normaliser` with the saved mean using the constructor.

Compared to using the keras generator directly it helped me have more flexibility on how to treat my data, and more clarity on what modification I am doing to it, which is not a trivial thing.
`samplwise_center` and `featurewise_center` are not the only ways to standardise images as [this discussion describes](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2559)